# npm keeps complaining after uninstalling yeoman and yeoman generators

Tags: npm, yeoman

I have uninstalled yeoman and two yeoman generators with:

```
sudo npm uninstall yeoman -g
sudo npm uninstall generator-angular -g
sudo npm uninstall generator-karma -g
```

But now when I list the currently installed packages, npm keeps complaining that it can't find yeoman, or those generators... (which is right, I just uninstalled them...)

When I run npm update, they even get re-installed! argh! why!

```
npm ls -g --depth=0

/usr/local/lib
├── bower@1.7.1
├── browserify@12.0.1
├── express-generator@4.13.1
├──  error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/package.json
├──  error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-karma/package.json
├── grunt-cli@0.1.13
├── npm@3.5.3
├── typescript@1.7.5
└──  error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/package.json
```

And also a LOT more errors (won't post them all here), starting with

```
npm ERR! error in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/package.json'
npm ERR! extraneous: wiredep /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/wiredep
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to clean the npm cache? Try this:

```
1. cd to your npm directory (/usr/local/lib/node_modules, I guess)
2. sudo rm -rf ~/.npm
3. sudo npm cache clean
```

Comment: This fixed the problem, although I'd much rather use "npm uninstall" to remove packages. I do not seem to have privileges (with or without sudo) to use 'npm uninstall'. How could I fix this?

Comment: `npm uninstall <name>` removes the module from node_modules, but not package.json. Try `npm uninstall <name> --save` to also delete the dependency from package.json. Try `npm -g uninstall <name> --save` to delete the dependency globally.